# Why does calling my api via python give an invalid date format whilst in java it does not (with the same string)

Tags: java, python, spring, datetime

I have a Java API using spring:

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Retrieve Tasks Results", notes = "Getting Successful Run Results for an Egg, Task, within date range")
@GetMapping(value = "{eggID}/tasks/{taskIDs}/results", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, List<TaskResult>>> getTasksRunResults(@PathVariable("eggID") String eggID,
                                                             @PathVariable("taskIDs") List<String> taskIDs,
                                                             @RequestParam(value = "fromDate", required = true)
                                                                 @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z")
                                                                         Date fromDate,
                                                             @RequestParam(value = "toDate", required = true)
                                                                 @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z")
                                                                         Date toDate) throws MoLiException {
```

Which I can call using this url:

```
String s = "/eggs/00000000-0333-0001-0002-000000000000/tasks/[00000000-0222-0026-0000-000000000000]/results?fromDate=2010-01-15 18:25:48.104 +0000&toDate=2026-01-15 18:25:48.104 +0000";
return mockMvc.perform(get(s).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
```

However, when I try using the same string via python code:

```
url = '/eggs/00000000-0333-0001-0002-000000000000/tasks/[00000000-0222-0026-0000-000000000000]/results?fromDate=2010-01-15 18:25:48.104 +0000&toDate=2026-01-15 18:25:48.104 +0000'
response = request_handler.send_request(url)
```

I get the following error:

```
    Exception: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date] for value '2010-01-15 18:25:48.104  0000'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2010-01-15 18:25:48.104  0000" is malformed at " 0000". Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date] for value '2010-01-15 18:25:48.104  0000'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2010-01-15 18:25:48.104  0000" is malformed at " 0000"
```

Can someone explain why, or at least give me something I can try?

PS. request handler code is:

```
    def send_request(self, action, method="GET",  **kwargs):
    request_arguments = {
        "method": method,
        "url": self._build_url(self.url, action),
        "headers": self._get_headers(**kwargs),
        "data": kwargs["data"] if "data" in kwargs else {},
        "verify": False
    }

@staticmethod
def _build_url(*args):
    url = "".join(args)
    return url
```

Comment: Umm... forgive me if I'm being stupid, but isn't the error trace you've included from java? :)

Comment: So, when the python code calls the java code, the java API returns that error back to the python code :-)